# Sitecore services client 403 when login called from different web application

Tags: authentication, login, webapi, sitecore-services-client

TL;DR: Sitecore services client 403 when login called from a different web application (IIS process), but not when called from Postman

**PROBLEM:**
RESTful Web API (web service) written in C# running on IIS/Azure (different machine than Sitecore) calling Sitecore services client.  Calling the endpoint `/sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login` over the network via HTTP always returns HTTP status code 403 Forbidden.

To be clear: I am using the Sitecore Restful  API  directly.  Not using JavaScript.  Not using SPEAK components.

**SYMPTOMS:**
Calling `/sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login` works with Postman and a console test app I wrote to POST data.  These work after I changed the "Sitecore.Services.Client.config" file from the default "ServicesLocalOnlyPolicy" to "ServicesOnPolicy".

Worked with Sitecore v8.x, but stopped working once we upgraded to Sitecore v9.x

**WHAT I'VE TRIED:**

- Other settings changed, but have no affect, in the Sitecore services client config:

> ```
> <setting name="Sitecore.Services.AllowToLoginWithHttp" value="true" />
> <setting name="Sitecore.Services.AllowAnonymousUser" value="true" />
> ```

- Searched Google, StackExchange, StackOverflow, and I read the Sitecore documentation ("Developer's  Guide to Sitecore.Services.Client"), but no resolution.
- I checked IIS logs for more detail on the 403, but nothing.
- Nothing in the Sitecore logs - I don't see anything regarding this error.

What else should I check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Sitecore services can be accessed from the local host machine only without log in (`ServicesLocalOnlyPolicy`). `ServicesOnPolicy` will allow you to log in through  "`/sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login`" and get the necessary token/cookie depending on your setup. If you want to bypass this behavior you can add your controller to allowed controllers section.

```
     <api>
       <services>
        <configuration type="Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Configuration.ServicesConfiguration, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure">
          <allowedControllers hint="list:AddController">
            <allowedController desc="MyController">MyNamespace, MyDll</allowedController>
          </allowedControllers>
        </configuration>
      </services>
    </api>
```

Comment: Perhaps there is a mis-understanding.  I have a RESTful web service on a different machine calling the Sitecore services client over HTTP, making an HTTP Post to /sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login.  I don't see how my adding what you suggest will help.  Can you explain?

Comment: Have you checked showconfig.aspx to ensure ServiceOnPolicy is correctly patched there?

Comment: Yes, it shows:
<setting name="Sitecore.Services.SecurityPolicy" value="Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.Security.ServicesOnPolicy, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure" patch:source="Sitecore.Services.Client.config"/>